# LVM + LUKS is this error okay?

Tags: debian, lvm, luks, cryptsetup, dm-crypt

I have a encrypted partition, inside it there exist LVM `/` and `/home`.

When I start PC it says.

```
Volume group "vg" not found
Cannot process volume group vg
Please unlock disk sdc2_crypt
```

After I type password

```
Couldn't find device with uuid ***-***-***-***
   Couldn't find device with uuid ***-***-***-***
   Refusing activation of partial LV vg/home. Use '--activationmode partial' to override.
cryptsetup: sdc2_crypt: setup up successfully
```

Is this a error that I should fix or it's okay ? If this is a error how to fix it ?

Comment: Did you do a Kernel upgrade? Does it work with the earlier version of the kernel?

Comment: @WGRM No, I just installed Debian. When I unlock disk and login in system I have / and /home and their size is that one that I choose when I was installing and setting up LVM. That's why I ask it's real error or it's fake error because of disk encryption

Answer (score 1):

The first messages (before typing the password) are normal: the system is searching for the volume group, but cannot find it because it's on an encrypted disk/partition.
In other words, this message is normal and expected on current Debian 10 and can be ignored.

(If anyone knows how to tell Debian 10 initramfs that the LUKS encryption should be unlocked *before* making the first attempt to probe for LVM, that knowledge would be appreciated.)

The second set of messages suggests that the system is also trying to mount the filesystem on LV `vg/home` before the encrypted disk is unlocked.

With the default configuration, the initramfs boot phase will only aim to unlock just the one encrypted volume that contains your root filesystem, and activate just the one LV that contains your root filesystem. Anything more than that is left for the "main" boot process, after the system has transitioned from initramfs to using the real root filesystem. If you need multiple LUKS encrypted volumes unlocked or multiple filesystems mounted in the initramfs phase, you will need to explicitly configure that.

Have you done something to cause the initramfs to mount your `/home` filesystem? Unless you're doing something very special, that is probably not necessary. But even so, the system will make further attempts to activate any available LVs and mount all the filesystems listed in `/etc/fstab` later in the boot process, so the second set of messages may also be ignorable.

You should probably find out which device the error message `Couldn't find device with uuid ***-***-***-***` refers to, by noting down the UUID and once the system is up and running, using `lsblk -o +UUID` or `blkid` to list the UUIDs of all the filesystems and identifying the matching device. If it is not `sdc2_crypt`, part of your `/home` filesystem might not be fully contained within the encrypted volume, which will cause some files on that filesystem to not be protected by the encryption.

Run `lvdisplay --maps /dev/vg/home` to see where all the parts of the `vg/home` LV are located. If under `--- Segments ---` it mentions any physical volumes that are not encrypted volumes (like `sdc2_crypt`), you have this problem. If you have enough unallocated space on an encrypted volume that belongs to the same LVM volume group (check with the `pvs` command), you can use `pvmove` to move the wayward parts of the LV onto an encrypted PV - even while the `/home` filesystem is mounted and in use.

Comment: `If anyone knows how to tell Debian 10 initramfs that the LUKS encryption should be unlocked before making the first attempt to probe for LVM, that knowledge would be appreciated.` : that comment is still relevant today (2023, Debian 11). Would be great if some Debian maintainers could fix this.